# Find records on one excel worksheet (PO Generator) that match records on another excel worksheet. (PO Log) Copy & paste the rows to the PO Log

Tags: excel, vba

So far the code i have.... takes the original Order on the PO Generator and copies it to the PO Log which is fine as long as they are new orders. My problem arises when i need to update a previous order. I would like it to find the original order and update the ref cell. Please help.... Excel 2003

```
Sub Get_Po()
'
' Get_Po Macro
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim dest As Range

Set ws1 = Sheets("PO GENERATOR")
Set ws2 = Sheets("PO LOG")
Set dest = ws2.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Offset(1)


Sheets("PO GENERATOR").Select
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>"
ws1.Range("2:5135").Copy
dest.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Type II Log").Select


End Sub
```

Comment: Is ms-Access an option?  It is designed to handle just this type of situation with ease.

Comment: Spider~Unfortunately its not....

Comment: Danny...  Did this work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that should work.  I have tested it and it does what you are looking for.  A few key points to watch for are.  What row and column your PO Generator starts at, and what row and column your PO Log information starts in.

```
    Dim a As String
Dim lastRow As String

lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
'   Variable for PO#
a = Sheets("PO GENERATOR").Range("A1").Value

Sheets("PO GENERATOR").Select
'   Adjust to whatever row your PO is located
Rows(1).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("PO LOG").Select

'   Modify the Columns(1) to whatever column number your PO# is located
'   Search For PO number
Dim cellrow As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    rng1 = a
    strSearch = rng1
        Set aCell = Sheets("PO LOG").Columns(1).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                                    SearchFormat:=False)

        MsgBox aCell & vbCrLf & aCell.Row
        cellrow = aCell.Row

'   Modify Range("A") to whatever column you PO is located
If cellrow = 0 Then
Range("A" & lastRow).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
    Else:
        Rows(cellrow).EntireRow.Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial
End If
```

Good Luck!!!